# nginx location proxy_pass of URL

Tags: nginx, nginx-location, nginx-reverse-proxy, nginx-config

In my nginx configuration I want to proxy_pass the following URL

Origin URL:

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/SOME-SERVICE/sub-path
```

Proxied Path:

```
http://2.2.2.2:1234/SOME-SERVICE/sub-path
```

The **SOME-SERVICE** value will have different values like:

```
http://1.1.1.1:8080/user-service/sub-path
http://1.1.1.1:8080/auth-service/sub-path
```

How should I write location path pattern to match the generic **SOME-SERVICE** value and proxy the URL with this value?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
location /*-service/ { // your stuff goes here }
```

Or, if you have a list of service-names

```
location /(user|auth)-service/ { // your stuff goes here }
```

Comment: The **SOME-SERVICE** does not follow a specific naming pattern and I don't know the list of services in advance ...

Comment: Do you simply want to allow all requests to go through?